# NodeJS Express - Show URL without using html extension

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am using Express 4.12.3 to serve out static files for a web site. I want to be able to navigate to example.com/mypage which would retrieve /mypage.html. In other words I want to be able to pull up the page without having to type in the .html extension in the URL.

My code looks like this:

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var server      = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(4000);
```

I can access my page in the browser while using the .html extension but get a not found when dropping the extension. Any ideas how to configure my express server to allow this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the `extensions` option to include fallback file extensions to try:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {
  extensions: ['html']
}));
```

Comment: That was the ticket. Exactly what I was looking for. Kind of feel sheepish, since its such a simple solution. Wonder how i missed that in the documentation.

Comment: And is there some simple way to account for trailing slashes without needing to use a dependency like express-slash?